# UWP save text in file

Tags: c#, xaml, file-io, uwp

I created in XAML 1 BUTTON and 2 TEXTBOXES with names UserInputTextBox and StatusTextBox. Then i created in MainPage.xaml.cs code to open file and save text to file:

```
FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();       
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    // Set properties on the file picker such as start location and the type 
    // of files to display.
    picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
    picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");

    // Show picker enabling user to pick one file.
    StorageFile result = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

    if (result != null)
    {
        try
        {
            // Use FileIO to replace the content of the text file
            await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(result, UserInputTextBox.Text);

            // Display a success message
            StatusTextBox.Text = "Status: File saved successfully";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Display an error message
            StatusTextBox.Text = "Status: error saving the file - " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
    else
        StatusTextBox.Text = "Status: User cancelled save operation";
}
```

and if i write to UserInputTextBox text then this text will be in file(.txt) but my problem is if i write to UserInputTextBox text second time, first text will be changed to second text. What i want to do is if i write text to UserInputTextBox so this text must be saved and if i write text there second time, there will be two texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think about what (Text)files are and how they work. In any case, you're looking to Append text rather than to Overwrite it.

```
 //await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(result, UserInputTextBox.Text);
   await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(result, UserInputTextBox.Text);
```

Try this and you will see that the results are not separated in anyway. For that you can research the NewLine character(s) or look at `AppendLinesAsync()`.